# Virtual Directory App within a Asp.net MVC app

Tags: iis-6, asp.net-mvc-routing, virtual-directory, screwturn

I am having issues trying to host screwturn wiki as a virtual directory application within my current domain.

the domain is hosted as something.com and the wiki would look like something.com/wiki

when i browse to something.com/wiki I get

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

Why is the virtual directory falling back to the root application. Shouldn't it be its own application boundary?

I have also added to the root mvc app

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*path}", new { path = @"wiki\/(.*)" });
```

This still has not solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution.

Thanks to Rick Strahls blog http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/133041.aspx

The solution was rather simple.  Add the below to your too web application

```
<location inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>   
    .........
    </system>
</location>
```

This solved my problem.